# What's the logic behind addition of 0101 with 5 in C?

Tags: c, binary

One of my friends asked me the output of this code and I just got shocked after running this code. The output of this code is 70. Please explain why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()

{
 int var = 0101;
 var = var+5;
 printf("%d",var);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Constants starting with `0` are in *octal* base. `0101` is the same as `65`.

Comment: I believe the leading 0 of var is actually , making it octal 101 = 65.

Comment: Simpler demonstration: `printf("%d", 0101);`

Comment: Q: Why do C programmers confuse Halloween and Christmas?  A: Because Oct 31 = Dec 25.

Answer (score 11):

The C Standard dictates that a numeric constant beginning with 0 is an *octal constant* (i.e. base-8) in [§ 6.4.4.1 (Integer constants)](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.1).

The value 101 in base 8 is 65 in base 10, so adding 5 to it (obviously) produces 70 in base 10.

Try changing your format specifier in `printf` to `"%o"` to observe the octal representation of `var`.

Answer (score 5):

It is because of **Integer Literals**. A number with leading `0` denoted that the number is an *octal* number. You can also use `0b` for denoting *binary number*, for *hexadecimal number* it is `0x` or `0X`. You don't need to write any thing for *decimal*. See the code bellow.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int binary = 0b10;
    int octal=010;
    int decimal = 10;
    int hexa = 0x10;
    printf("%d %d %d %d\n", octal, decimal, hexa, binary);
}
```

For more information visit [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_constants.htm).

Comment: I don't believe that the syntax `0bnnn` is currently supported by the C standard, though many compilers have it as an extension

Answer (score 4):

Not shocking at all. [C11 Standard - 6.4.4.1 Integer constants(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.1p3) provides:

> `"An octal constant consists of the prefix 0 optionally followed by a
>   sequence of the digits 0 through 7 only."`

Some compilers, such as gcc, provide extension for specifying binary constants, e.g. [GCC Manual - 6.64 Binary Constants using the ‘0b’ Prefix](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Binary-constants.html) But note, this is a non-standard extension.

Combining both in your example would give:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    int var = 0101,
        bar = 0b0101;
    var = var + 5;
    bar = bar + 5;
    printf ("var: %d\nbar: %d\n", var, bar);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/octbin
var: 70
bar: 10
```

Answer (score 2):

Inicially var is in octal numeric system, so  `var=0101` is equal to `001000001` in binary system or equal to `65` in decimal system.

for example in this code you can show `65` as the var inicial value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()

{
  int var = 0101;
  printf("initial value. var=%o\n",var);
  var = var+5;

  printf("result of var+5. var=%d\n",var);
  printf("%d\n",var);
  return 0;
}
```

You'll get this output:

```
initial value. var=65
result of var+5. var=70
70
```